# How should a ViewModel interact with a Repository?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, repository-pattern, observablecollection

I am learning to build an application using MVVM, and I have the following situation:

- A ViewModel should display a list of objects of type `Examination`. This list will be databound to a `ListView` in the View, from where it will be filtered, and the user will select the `ActiveExamination` for further use.
- A Repository, which "lives" in the Model layer, should "behave as an in-memory collection of domain objects", and is instanced inside the ViewModel.

Now my question is: should the Repository BE the collection to be databound to the view, or should it only be the "datasource" to a Property implementing INPC? For example, from the following possibilities, is one of them correct and the other wrong, or both wrong...?

```
// example where the list is replaced in order to be changed;

// ViewModel class (part of it)
public class ThisViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    public List<Examination> ExaminationList {
        get { return _examinationList; }
        set { _examinationList = value;
              NotifyOfPropertyChange("ExaminationList"); }
    }
}


var repo = new ExaminationRepository();
ThisViewModel.ExaminationList = repo.getAll().where(ex => ex.Value > 20).ToList();
```

Second option

```
// Example where the very property IS a repository

// ViewModel class (part of it)
public class ThisViewModel : ViewModelBase {

    // the List is actually a repository in disguise.
    IEnumerable _examinationList = new ExaminationRepository();

    public List<Examination> ExaminationList {
        get { return _examinationList; }
        set { _examinationList = value;
              // This should be "NotifyOfCollectionChange", I guess...
              NotifyOfPropertyChange("ExaminationList"); }
    }
}
```

Most probably I am quite confused/mistaken here, but my application is rather small and simple architecture-wise, and I really don't plan to use most frameworks and advanced concepts I have seen associated with this kind of problem (ORM, IoC, DI), instead I am mostly concerned to "how to properly handle a mutable, reppository-based collection in a WPF/MVVM Databinding environment".

EDIT: some context about my application:
The application is one that performs clinical examinations. It has a list of Patients, where each Patient has its Examinations. There is a Patient repository and an Examinations repository. When I select a Patient in the PatientList, the ExaminationsList of that patient displays the matching Examinations from the Examinations repo. User actions on the Patients and Examinations are CRUD, or most specifically BREAD (Browse, Read, Edit, Add and Delete).

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: "how to properly handle a mutable, reppository-based collection in a WPF/MVVM Databinding environment" --- Why you want it mutable? Don't you want it to be immutable? And it depends on the case on how you want to use the ExaminationList, is it gonna be just displaying data from the database without the user having the ability to add items back to the database?

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis I edited the question with more context.

Comment: Then what I would do is make a ObservableCollection<T> property and lazy load the backing property to get the items in the database, and any succeeding items to the collection will be handled properly when they Add/Edit/Delete. Your separation of layers is fine, you just have to use it correctly in the ViewModel. I disagree with Sheridan's answer that you should always have separate collections to fill/display in the UI. Nope nope nope.

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis thanks very much so far. Just another doubt: you mention "lazy load the becking property" and "any succeeding items will be hendled properly". Is it implemented with help of `ObservableCollection<T>` itself, or should I override or implement code, or yet should I put code in setters/getters...? A bit confused, still...

Comment: It's not implemented by the class you implement it yourself. It's like this public ObservableCollection<T> Patients { get { if(_patients == null) { _patients == //Call the repository here } return _patients; }

Then on some other part of your code you'll just call Patients.Add or something or Remove, and these are built in with the class.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, for best separation in large applications, you should *always* use separate collections to fill from the database and then to display in the UI. This *does* mean that you'll have to iterate through the collection twice, but this is often required in WPF anyway, as we like to add in extra display properties for the UI, such as `IsSelected` or `IsFocused` (if we are filling view model objects).

The main reason for this really though is to allow us to interface our various layers in the application so that we can test each layer independently. If you have no requirement to do this, then maybe it's not so important.

I've always wondered why Microsoft implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanging` interfaces in their auto generated classes (from Linq2SQL for instance) when using these classes in the UI directly breaks the separation between layers that they themselves are always telling developers to adhere to.

UPDATE >>>

I would say that for a small application, it really doesn't matter how and where you do these things. Sometimes when writing a really small application, I don't even bother using MVVM. Creating layers and/or implementing an MVVM folder structure all add additional development time and extra code and I feel that they are only useful *if* you;

a) will be testing the individual layers of your application separately, or

b) might be likely at some stage in the future to need to 'swap out' one or more of the layers, eg. to move from a `SQL` database to an `Oracle` database for instance, or to move from a WPF UI to a web-based UI.

Comment: Would that mean that my first code block is adequate? My application is rather small and simple, and I'm not sure I quite understood your considerations (I have not much experience with databound collections yet).

Comment: Yes, I would use something like your first example. I often put my data accessing code into a method named `Refresh` that is called in the constructor and then also give the users a `Command` that they can use to call this method, eg. the users can refresh the data in each view by clicking on a `Button` in the UI that is bound to the `Command` that calls the `Refresh` method internally.